Assigning codes to nodes such that codes are unique and create two groups which share common properties
We are given N, and we know there are 1..N objects in group 1 and N+1...2*N objects in group 2. Every object in group 1 is connected with each other, and every object in group 2 is connected with each other (inside group).
There is a list consisting of length p (1 <= p <= N^2)  of numbers [a, b], where a is object from group 1 and b is object from group 2. The pair [a, b] means that there must be connection between object a and b. If there is no [a, b] pair in the list, then there cannot be connection between them.
For every object, we need to set unique code representing this object, which is string constisting of characters {A, B, C} with length up to M and N + 1 <= M <= 3N. Given two codes x and y of equal length, if there is index i such that x_i == y_i, then there is connection between object represented by code x and y.
I tried solving it starting with setting characters in codes that will create required connections between objects of two distinct groups.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);
    cout.tie(nullptr);

    int n, p, M;
    cin >> n >> p >> M;

    set<int> groups;
    set<pair<int, int>> connections;
    for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i)
    {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;

        groups.insert(b);
        connections.insert({a, b});
    }

    vector<string> codes(2 * n + 1, string(M, ' '));
    int pos = 1;
    set<int> a_pos;
    for (const int b : groups)
    {
        for (int a = 1; a <= n; ++a)
        {
            if (connections.find({a, b}) == connections.end())
                continue;

            codes[a][pos] = 'A';
            codes[b][pos] = 'A';
        }

        ++pos;
        a_pos.insert(pos);
    }
}

To use as minimum characters as possible to create required connections, I grouped connections basing on their endpoints (objects from group 2). This way, assume N = 3, if we have connections e.g. 1 -> 4, 2 -> 4, we can use one character at some position to connect both 1 and 2 to 4. Also, I assumed my codes will always be of maximum possible length.
However, I have problem to come up with logic that will ensure uniqueness of every code. We can see that if we imagine the connections between objects as a graph, then objects become nodes, there are two main components (group 1 and group 2), and then we have connections between these components, so it's a bit similar to a bipartite graph, but this observation didn't help me.
How can we solve that?
That's problem Satelity from XXXI Polish Olympiad in Informatics, stage I

Why do you mention that all the objects are connected to all the other objects in the same group?  It seems irrelevant.

Also, is M given or is it to be found?  If it's given then why isn't it just N+1?

@MattTimmermans 1. Because if all the objects in group are connected, it means that their codes have to contain at least one the same character at the same position. 2. M is input and that has been said in problem statement that it's greater or equal N+1 and lesser or equal to 3N.

Do all the codes have to be the same length?

@MattTimmermans Yes

that's a math question and the solution is arrived at by thinking and describing the solution, not by coding. coding is at best a demonstration. the task's description has issues too ("length up to M" and then the following range for M). you should just post the original assignment in the original language.

It's tricky, but you can always do this with codes of length N+1 or less.
First, partition each group into equivalence classes, where two objects are considered equivalent if they connect to the same set of other objects.
In each group, we count the number of equivalence classes that have connections to the other group.  The group with the smallest number will be designated the "target" group T, and the other group will be designated S.
Let E be the number of equivalence classes with connections in T.  We assign the first E code symbols as follows:

Each symbol position corresponds to an equivalence class with connections in T
For each object in group T, the code has B in the position for its equivalence class (if it has connections), and A elsewhere.
For each object in group S, the code has B for all the equivalence classes in T that it connects to, and C elsewhere.

Using E symbol positions, we have now accurately represented all of the connections between groups.  We need to use the remaining positions to connect all T objects to each other, connect all S objects to each other, and to distinguish objects in the same equivalence class, because they have the same codes so far.
Let C be the size of the largest equivalence class.  We always have E <= N+1-C, and so we have at least C remaining symbol positions.
Easy case
If C=1 (each object has distinct connections), then we only need to use one symbol position to join each group.  Set it to A for group T and B for group S.
Still easy case
If E <= N+1 - 2ceil(log2 C), then we have at least 2ceil(log2 C) positions available.
We allocate ceil(log2 C) positions for each group to record a unique index i to distinguish objects in the same equivalence class.  Within the group, its positions encode the index as a binary number using B and C, and set all the other group's positions to A.  This ensures that each group is connected within itself by the As, and not mistakenly connected to the other group, because the As won't match B or C.
Note that this easy case almost always applies.  The only times it doesn't apply are special cases with C=3 or C=5.
Hard cases C=3
If C=3 and the case is non-easy, then both groups must have N-2 equivalence classes, all with connections, leaving 3 positions to record the remaining information. If only one of the groups has a class of size 3 (let's say it's S), then encode the remaining positions like this (similar to the easy cases):
 Group  i  p0 p1 p2
--------------------
   S    0   A  B  B
   S    1   A  B  C
   S    2   A  C  B
   T    0   B  A  A
   T    1   C  A  A

Otherwise, both groups have exactly one class of size 3, and all the rest are size 1.  If the two big classes are connected, then encode the remaining positions like this:
 Group  i  p0 p1 p2
--------------------
   S    0   A  A  A
   S    1   A  A  C
   S    2   A  C  A
   T    0   B  B  B
   T    1   B  B  C
   T    2   B  C  B

The only case left is when the big classes are disconnected.  Find one T class that the big S class connects to, and give it an extra position.  Now there are 3 distinct ways to connect to that T class, and they can be used to distinguish the 3 members of the S class.  The remaining positions are encoded like so to distinguish the members of the T class:
 Group  i  p0 p1 
------------------
   T    0   B  B 
   T    1   B  C 
   T    2   C  B 
   S    x   A  A 

Note that even though these assignments don't connect the two object in group T with i = 1 or 2, they will still be connected, because they connect to all the same objects in S.
Hard Cases C=5
If C=5 and the case is non-easy, then both groups must have N-4 equivalence classes, all with connections, leaving 5 positions to record the remaining information. If only one of the groups has a class of size 5 (let's say it's S), then encode the remaining positions like this:
 Group  i  p0 p1 p2 p3 p4
--------------------------
   S    0   B  B  B  A  A
   S    1   B  B  C  A  A
   S    2   B  C  B  A  A
   S    3   B  C  C  A  A
   S    4   C  B  B  A  A
   T    0   A  A  A  B  B
   T    1   A  A  A  B  C
   T    2   A  A  A  C  B
   T    3   A  A  A  C  C

Otherwise, both groups have exactly one class of size 5, and the rest are size 1.  If the two big classes are connected, then assign the remaining positions like this:
 Group  i  p0 p1 p2 p3 p4
--------------------------
   S    0   A  A  A  A  A
   S    1   A  A  A  A  C
   S    2   A  A  A  C  A
   S    3   A  A  A  C  C
   S    4   A  A  C  A  A
   T    0   B  B  B  B  B
   T    1   B  B  B  B  C
   T    2   B  B  B  C  B
   T    3   B  B  B  C  C
   T    4   B  B  C  B  B

Finally, in the last hard case, both groups have exactly one class of size 5, and the two big classes are not connected.  In this case, find one T class that the big S class connects to, and give it 2 extra positions.  Now there are 7 distinct ways to connect to that T class, and they can be used to distinguish the 5 members of the S class.  The remaining 3 positions are encoded like so to distinguish the members of the T class:
 Group  i  p0 p1 p2
--------------------
   T    0   B  B  B
   T    1   B  B  C
   T    2   B  C  B
   T    3   B  C  C
   T    4   C  B  B
   S    x   A  A  A 

Conclusion
That completes the non-easy cases, all of them covered with N+1 symbols.

Indeed, a terrifying math problem. Thanks :)

I hope I haven't missed anything, but I think the following algorithm is a possible solution for M > 2N.
Let's start with the inner group connections: since every object in group 1 is connected with each other, and every object in group 2 is connected with each other, we can set x_0 = 'A' for each object in group 1 and x_0 = 'B' in group 2.
Then, we handle the inter group connections with x_i, i = 1..2N. Let's consider each object in group 1 (for i up to N) and in group 2 (after N+1). We can set x_i = 'A' for this object, and x_i = 'B' for every other object in the same group (as all these objects are connected with each other, they can share the same x_i). Let's now consider every object in the other group connected to the object i. We can set x_i = 'A' for those objects too, and x_i = 'C' for every other object in this same group.
With this method, we handle the p connections and the inner group connections, and we make sure that two disconnected objects never share a common part of their code (one of them will always have x_i = 'B' or 'C' for i > 0). The length of the code is 2N+1, which is lower or equal to 3N if we suppose N >= 1.
Let's check the uniqueness of the codes: let's consider two objects sharing the same code x_i == y_i for i = 0..2N. Since x_0 == y_0, they belong to the same group. If this group is 1, it means that x_i == y_i == 'B' for every i = 1..N except one single index which is, according to the way we built the code, the index of the object. So the two objects are the same one. If the group is 2, we can proceed the same way.
Let's try the method on your example with N = 3 and 1 -> 4, 2 -> 4. The algorithm returns:
1 | AABBACC
2 | ABABACC
3 | ABBACCC
4 | BAACABB
5 | BCCCBAB
6 | BCCCBBA


Codes length is restricted by M. It can be as low as N + 1

I would assume you can only run the algorithm to N not to 2*N, as you still handle the connections once.

@Szyszka947 Ok I didn't understand M was an input. I change my answer to explain it doesn't work for M <= 2N.

@HansOlsson You are right about the connections, but you won't have unicity of the codes (objects 5 and 6 will have the same code in my example).

Concept
The object codes are build up one column at a time
The first column distinguishes between the groups: A for 1, B for 2
The i+1th column links objects via the ith link: A if group 1 in link, B otherwise, A if group 2 in link, C otherwise
The last three columns are used to ensure the codes are unique

Algorithm
// identify objects linked together in each group
LOOP over objecs
  set code to A if in group 1
  set code to B if ion group 2

// idebtify objects linked between groups
LOOP over links
   LOOP over group 1 objects
      IF object in first part of link
          add A to code
      ELSE
          add B to code
   LOOP over group 2 objects
      IF object in second part of link
          add A to code
      ELSE
          add C to code

// ensure codes are unique
LOOP over objects 
     add permutation of ABC to code

Application code
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int N;
std::vector<std::string> vcodes;
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vlinks;

// Generate example from question
void generate(int n)
{
    vcodes.clear();
    N = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        vcodes.push_back("A");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        vcodes.push_back("B");

    vlinks.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 4));
    vlinks.push_back(std::make_pair(2, 4));
}
/*
I assume that '4' indicates the first object in the second group

Convert the link indices to zero-based indepedently in each group

*/
void zerobase()
{
    for (auto &l : vlinks)
    {
        l.first -= 1;
        l.second -= N + 1;
    }
}

void link()
{
    for (auto &link : vlinks)
    {
        for (int object = 0; object < N; object++)
            if (object == link.first)
                vcodes[object] += "A";
            else
                vcodes[object] += "B";
        for (int object = 0; object < N; object++)
            if (object == link.second)
                vcodes[N + object] += "A";
            else
                vcodes[N + object] += "C";
    }
}

void makeUnique()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vus;
    char vc[] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
    do
    {
        std::string us = "xxx";
        us[0] = vc[0];
        us[1] = vc[1];
        us[2] = vc[2];
        vus.push_back(us);
    } while (std::next_permutation(vc, vc + 3));
    for (int i = 0; i < 2*N; i++)
    {
        vcodes[i] += vus[i];
    }
}

void displayCodes()
{
    for (auto &c : vcodes)
        std::cout << c << "\n";
}

main()
{
    generate(3);
    zerobase();
    link();
    makeUnique();
    displayCodes();
    return 0;
}


Output:
AABABC
ABAACB
ABBBAC
BAABCA
BCCCAB
BCCCBA

Larger Problems
There may not be enough permutations of {A,B,C} to ensure all objects have a unique code.  In this case, use permutation of permutations e.g permute the array { ABC, ... , CBA }  There are 3! ( = 6 ) permutations of ABC. If you then permute those 6, you get 6! unique permutations. Very quickly you get enough unique combinations for any purpose.
I have committed code to the github repo demonstrating how this works.  I have also added some code the check that the generatedcodes are indeed unique.
Here are the results for n = 9
all codes are unique
AABABCACBBACBCACABCBA
ABAABCACBBACBCACBACAB
ABBABCACBBACCABBCACBA
ABBABCACBBACCABCBABCA
ABBABCACBBACCBABCACAB
ABBABCACBBACCBACABBCA
ABBABCACBBCABACCABCBA
ABBABCACBBCABACCBACAB
ABBABCACBBCACABBACCBA
BCCABCACBBCACABCBABAC
BCCABCACBBCACBABACCAB
BCCABCACBBCACBACABBAC
BCCABCACBCABBACBCACBA
BCCABCACBCABBACCBABCA
BCCABCACBCABBCABACCBA
BCCABCACBCABBCACBABAC
BCCABCACBCABCBABACBCA
BCCABCACBCABCBABCABAC

Github repo:
https://github.com/JamesBremner/so78962741

I don't get why 3 characters are enough to be sure that codes are unique? Also, what does permutation of permutation changes? It's just another permutation of original set.

There are 3! ( = 6 ) permutations of  ABC.  If you then permute those 6, you get 6! unique permutations.  Very quickly you get enough unique combinations for any purpose.

Updated answer for larger problems.

Still don't get it. If I have permutation {B, A, C} (its one of these 3! = 6 permutations), and then permute the permutation {B, A, C} then I get permutation which was included in these 3! = 6 permutations, not something unique. Or maybe you mean that after 3! permutations are used, then I need 3 more characters in my code to provide uniqueness (so I have 6! permutations)? And something I didn't think about before, adding these permutations to object may result in additional connection between objects of different groups.

Please take a look at the code.  Even better, build and run the app yourself so you can see how it works.  I cannot explain it any more clearly than I have.
